# Python 3 difficulties to handle csv from url

Tags: csv, python-3.x, encoding, httplib2

I've been struggling this problem for a very long time, so I thought I'd ask for help.

I'm using [httplib2](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2) to get a csv and then I'm trying to open it but I'm facing issues (maybe encoding).

I have this following code :

```
url = "https://ws.webtrends.com/profiles/%s/period_type=trend&format=csv" % (profile_code)

h = httplib2.Http()
h.add_credentials('login', 'password')
response, content = h.request(url)
csv_data = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(content, 'utf-8'))

for idx,row in enumerate(csv_data):
    print (row)
```

I get the following error coming from the `codecs.iterdecode` line :

```
TypeError: can't concat bytes to int
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.